# Increase iPhone call history

Tags: iphone, call, history

How can see call history in iPhone one month back, i also tried with tried party software but that is not perfect , is the any solution from apple?

Comment: Call history is something that people, especially professionals, need to be able to access, for a multitude of reporting, financial and legal reasons. Unfortunately, Apple's AWOL approach to this part of their iOS has meant the market has proliferated with a multitude of software products that claim to do this and yet almost all appear to do it with wildly varying degrees of success and almost all, with false claims of being free. I am still looking for one that works and will post back, if, as and when I am successful.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. iPhone call history is limited to the last 100 entries. Older entries are hidden but they might be available through a 3rd-party app.

Answer (score 1):

Apple says the limit is the last 100 calls for all apple phones.  They do suggest two options:  your phone carrier may have an 18 mo history which you can get from them.  Also, there may be a 3rd party app you could install to get more.  The only ones I saw were paid apps, so please advise if anyone sees a free app that does this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend past the 100 entry limit.

[This app](https://www.imyfone.com/ios-data-recovery/iphone-call-log-history-increase/) claims to be able to access entries past the limit.

*Disclaimer*: I have no financial interest in, or any personal or professional connection with, iMyPhone Technology Co. Ltd.. I've never used their product(s), so I have no idea if they work. YMMV.