# How to access a full call history?

Tags: call, history

I need the call history for the month of September, 2022. My iPhone doesn’t show a full call history. Someone called me on the 9 of September and was a missed call. I need their cellphone number.

Comment: Please indicate the steps you've taken to access the call history, but have failed to do so. This [purchasable app](https://www.tenorshare.net/ads/iphone-data-recovery-win.html) claims to be able to do this. I have no experience with this app nor its developer. YMMV.

Comment: Call history isn't by time, it's by count. The phone shows the last 100. [Mine goes back to last December;) Various 3rd party apps claim the internal database is 1,000 & can be accessed by their own software. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256904/increase-iphone-call-history There are also claims that by deleting the 100 you can see [one at a time], you will reveal the previous 100… which does seem to be the case, though I only tested by deleting the newest three.

Comment: iMazing https://imazing.com shows me more than 100 calls.