# How many entries does the cal log actually store?

Tags: iphone, ios, call

Meet Bob. Bob’s iPhone stores X (about the last couple of months’ worth of) calls in its recent calls list. The list is full because when Bob makes a new call he squeezes the oldest call off the list. Yet one day he discovers that if he then deletes some call from the list, then the older ones reappear at the bottom.

So, they haven’t really been deleted but are simply no longer displayed in the list view. Where are these invisible calls stored, and how can one access them? How many old calls are actually stored in this way?

What is known about this mechanism in iOS?

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449131/how-to-access-a-full-call-history and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256904/increase-iphone-call-history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many entries does the cal log actually store?

**It is hard coded to store 100 calls.**  There are a couple of online resources that claim this (confirmed with Bing Chat/ChatGPT) and I wasn’t able to find anything official from Apple.  However, I did manually confirm this by counting my entries (conveniently, there are 10 entries per “screen” on the iPhone).

[image]

> Where are these invisible calls stored, and how can one access them?

If you need more than this, you need to contact your carrier.  I know from personal experience that AT&T, T-Mobile, USMobile, and Verizon (US carriers) all provide a full call history in the billing statements (PDF) and AT&T and Verizon both have a call log search function.  To get this info, you’ll need to contact your carrier.

There are third party options to export call data and manilulate it without needing carrier involvement. PhoneView was excellent in the past and [they now refer people to iMazing](https://imazing.com/phoneview?a=1) for this sort of functionality.

Comment: It *shows* the last 100 calls, but it definitely stores more. I tested this recently when a similar question came up. As the OP says, if you wipe some of the newer ones, older calls show up at the bottom of the list. I didn't test to see how far it would go. https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/449131/85275

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn’t go especially far at all. I tested it and it seemed to only take me a few minutes to reach the end of the stack, so to speak.

Comment: `(confirmed with Bing Chat/ChatGPT)` lol. This answer is most definitely wrong. If you delete a call from the list an earlier call moves up. So more than a 100 calls **must** be stored somewhere. I had a similar question with a better answer (however not super satisfatory). Which was closed by trigger happy mods that are too lazy to properly understand the issues being asked. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270912/retrieve-older-call-history-on-iphone